# Spring's nested transactions with different transactionManagers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm new to Spring's transaction management having troubles to tackle the following scenario of nested transactions while integrating Spring (3.2) and Hibernate (3.6).

I've declared two appContext files as following.

**File1) applicationContext-student.xml**

```
    <bean id="studentProjSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
        ...**dataSource1_on_Machine1**...
    </bean>
    <bean id="studentProjTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="studentProjSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="studentProjTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.my.univ.employee.dao.studentHibDao" scope="singleton" />

    <bean id="studentService" class="com.my.univ.student.service.studentServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
            <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao" />
    </bean>
```

**File2) applicationContext-employee.xml**

```
<bean id="employeeProjSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
            ........**dataSource2_on_Machine2**...
</bean>
<bean id="employeeProjTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="employeeProjSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="employeeProjTransactionManager" />

<bean id="employeeDao" class="com.my.univ.employee.dao.EmployeeHibDao" scope="singleton" />

<bean id="employeeService" class="com.my.univ.employee.service.EmployeeServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
        <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao" />
</bean>
```

Imported above two files in the following file.

**File3) applicationContext-university.xml**

```
<import resource="applicationContext-student.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-employee.xml" />

<bean id="personService" class="com.my.univ.person.service.PersonServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
        <property name="studentService" ref="studentService" />
        <property name="employeeService" ref="employeeService" />
</bean>
```

**Questions**

Let's assume that method level @Transactional annotations are provided with the right txManager names in studentService and employeeService but not in personService.

**Q1)** If I declare a method in personService as @Transactional, which txManager gets picked?

**Q2)** How does the nested txManager scenario work if the txManagers in the hierarchy are different from each other?

Ex: If a @Transactional method in personService invokes a @Transactional method in studentService and then another @Transactional method in employeeService (with in the same method of personService).

**Q3)** How does the commit, rollback elements work in above scenario.

**Q4)** Readonly operations vs Read/Write operations in above scenario.

It'd be great if anybody could clarify the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Transactional` annotation takes as a value the bean name of the transaction manager. From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html):

```
public abstract String value
A qualifier value for the specified transaction.
May be used to determine the target transaction manager, matching the qualifier value (or the bean name) of a specific PlatformTransactionManager bean definition.

Default:
""
```

So in your case, explicitly defining:

```
@Transactional("studentProjTransactionManager")
@Transactional("employeeProjTransactionManager")
```

should wrap transactionally using the right transaction manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I didn't specify the txName but only defined the annotation, which txManager would be picked in the personService?

Comment: Not sure which one is getting picked up, you can inspect at runtime putting a breakpoint which one is getting loaded. But is there a reason not to define the transaction manager to be used especially now that you have explicitly defined 2 of them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can declare it explicitly in student and employeeService. The point is if I defined the tx to be studentTx in the personService and do something that results in a nested hierarchy with employeeTxManager within, is it going to work?